# Using $.ajax to upload file and string: Either Illegal invocation or empty Form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

On a webpage, I need to upload both an image file and an ID string to the server. Usually, I do these things using `$.ajax`. As it often happens when uploading files, `$.ajax` threw an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` because the function by default tries to convert the file object into a string. It's common advice to set `processData` to `false` to prevent this.

But I cannot use this option:

- If I set `processData` to `false`, only an empty array is sent to the server. I can see in the developer tools that the Form Data object is empty and there's no data in the request object that reaches the server (I'm using PHP/Laravel).
- If I omit the option, I get an `Illegal invocation` error.

What's special about my code and what else can I do?

Below is most of the JS code. File uploads are triggered by dropping an image in the last cell of a table row. I need to upload both an image and an ID which is stored in the (hidden) first cell of the same table row.

```
<script>
  // dragover-listener omitted

  // Add listeners for drop event to each cell in last column
  let imageCells = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image'));
  imageCells.forEach(function(cell) {
    cell.addEventListener('drop', fileSelect);
  });

  // Handle drop event
  function fileSelect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get data for AJAX request: ID and new image
    let parentRow = event.target.closest('tr');
    let id = parentRow.cells[0].textContent;

    let data = {
      id:    id,
      image: event.dataTransfer.files[0]
    }

    // data is available
    console.log(data);

    let ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
      url:         '/map/set-image',
      type:        'POST',
      processData: false,
      data:        data
    });

    ajaxRequest.done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    // fail handler omitted
  }
</script>
```

*edit*: Some sample HTML

```
<tr>
    <td class="hidden">4</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">John</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Doe</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">john.doe@example.com</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">555 12345</td>
    <td class="image"><img src="/img/avatars/4.jpg"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to wrap your inputs with a form element and give it an id. Then use $.post instead:

```
$.post('/map/set-image', $("#yourFormId" ).serialize());
```

Note that you would need to create a hidden input in the form to send the ID string to the server.

Comment: There are no inputs, everything happens inside table cells. Also, there are more than 70 server generated table rows, and each of them can be used to upload an image. I added the HTML code for a sample row.

Answer (score 0):

Just to try something different, I used a `FormData` object (instead of a plain one) to collect my data. So I replaced

```
let data = {
  id:    id,
  image: event.dataTransfer.files[0]
}
```

with

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('image', event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
data.append('id', id);
```

Didn't work yet, I still had to replace the third line with `data.append('id', String(id));`

It seems the request failed because as I switched off the automatic conversion of the request data into strings (`processData: false`) the ID was treated as a number.

Note that the string conversion alone didn't do the trick, just using `String(id)` instead of `id`in the initial version doesn't work - I'd still like to know why.